# Read and validate a string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, validation

I'm new on C#, I'm getting

> "not all code paths return a value"

appreciate the help why, or how I should write it.

```
  private string ReadDescription(out bool success)
    {
        success = false;
        if (txtDescription.Text == "")
        {
            GiveMessage("Ivalid description");
            success = false;
        }
        else
            success = true;
```

//here is were the method is going.

```
 private ShoppingItem ReadInput(out bool success)
    {
        success = false;
        ShoppingItem item = new ShoppingItem();
        item.Descritption = ReadDescription(out success); //<----
        if (!success)
            return null;
        item.Amount = ReadAmount(out success);
        if (!success)
            return null;
        item.Unit = ReaUnit(out success);
        if (!success)
            return item;
    }
```

Comment: @Sefe what an awesome source! Thanks for that!

Comment: `"not all code paths return a value"` this means that if you create a method that has a return type, you need to a `return "of that type"`

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks to the guys who made it. Saves you a lot of words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, altrought the error in your first method is given by a simple missing `return success;` at the end... I find your code lacks a little bit of readability and should invert some of his logics. Let's refactor it a little bit, ok?

Just keep in mind I don't know your framework so I'm working on a best effort here:

```
private ShoppingItem ReadInput()
{
    ShoppingItem item = new ShoppingItem();

    // a whitespace filled property should be invalid too in my opinion
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDescription.Text))
        return null;

    item.Description = txtDescription.Text; // Maybe apply some special formatting...

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAmount.Text))
        return null;

    item.Amount= txtAmount.Text; // Maybe apply some special formatting or a type conversion...

    // and so on...

    return item;
}
```

The use of `out` and `bool` looked like an overkill to me and didn't really make sense... and if you want to stick with your approach, I recommend you to switch the logic of your method `ReadDescription` (and all the other similar methods) as follows:

```
private Boolean TryReadDescription(out String description)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDescription.Text))
    {
        description = "Invalid Description";
        return false;
    }

    description = txtDescription.Text;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your ReadDescription function might have been cut off (I'm not seeing a closing bracket), but assuming that's all there is to it you're missing a return. Adding

```
return success;
```

to the end of ReadDescription() should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to `return success;` as the last statement of the method.

e.g

```
private string ReadDescription(out bool success)
{
        success = false;
        if (txtDescription.Text == "")
        {
            GiveMessage("Ivalid description");
            success = false;
        }
        else
            success = true;  
        return success;
}
```

The `ReadInput` method should either `return null;` or `return item;` as the last statement of the method. You might be completely sure that one of the `if` conditions within the method will always be met but the compiler is not smart enough to deduce this hence the need for a `return null;` or `return item;` depending on which one you find most approriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReadInput` method returns a value.

You only return a value inside if statements.

You need a default `return null;` statement at the end of the method.

Also, we can’t see all of `ReadDescription`.

Answer (score 0):

On your first method you are declaring a return type of string not bool, you will probably want to change that to bool.